# hide divs using javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I would like to hide divs that have no ids associated with them using javascript. For example, in sharepoint `.ms-globalbreadcrumb` doesn't have an id.

```
frame = document.getElementById('frame1'); 
frame.contentWindow.document.getElementById('ctl00_PlaceHolderGlobalNavigation_PlaceHolderGlobalNavigationSiteMap_GlobalNavigationSiteMap').style.display='none';
```

The above code works for pieces that have ids but I am not sure how to achieve this for other divs with no ids.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You would make your life a lot easier using something that normalizes access to the DOM, so that the same code (for everything - forms, events, object properties, etc etc) works across all browsers. Using [JQuery](http://jquery.com) it's just:

```
$('div').hide();
```

to hide all divs...and there are a huge range of ['selectors'](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to refine your selection.

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1**
If you want to hide all divs with no id then you would have to loop all divs and hide them based on that criteria. (*find the divs with the [`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName)*)

```
var alldivs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for( var i = 0; i < alldivs.length; i++) {    
       alldivs[i].style.display = "none";
    }
```

---

**Case 2**
If you want to find elements based on a class, like in  your example the `.ms-globalbreadcrumb` then (*find the elements with the class with the [`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName)*)

```
var allbyclass = document.getElementsByClassName('ms-globalbreadcrumb');
for( var i = 0; i < allbyclass.length; i++) {    
       allbyclass[i].style.display = "none";
    }
```

(*the `getElementsByClassName` will not work for pre IE9 versions of IE*)

example with both cases at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/H3nNr/

---

**suggestion**

Use [jQuery](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) which allows for a wide variety of [selectors](http://www.jquery.com) and complex [traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) of the DOM to find what you want..

- Case 1 in jQuery would be `$('div:not([id])').hide();`
- Case 2 in jQuery would be `$('.ms-globalbreadcrumb').hide();`

Comment: I am using jquery 1.5.1 min js using the code you provided it does not seem to hide it. Any ideas why?

Comment: @elmander, i had an error in the jquery examplew. The case 1 example would hide all divs, not those without `id`. Now i fixed it to only select those without `id`.

Comment: @elmander, also make sure you are dealing with divs, as we are specifically targeting those in the examples. If the elements in the dom are `span` it will not select them.

Answer (score 0):

If you can locate the divs in the DOM, then you should be able to hide them. For example, if a parent / grandparent etc div has an ID, you can go down the DOM tree using Javascript until you have found the element you want to hide.

```
var elem = document.getElementById("topelement");
var elem2 = elem.firstChild.firstChild;
elem2.style.display = "none";
```

JQuery has lots of selectors for making this kind of thing easy.

Answer (score 0):

so theres other methods you can use
you can get them by tagname or classes

```
 document.getElementsByClassName
 document.getElementsByTagName
```

they return list of elements you need to iterate threw

so your example shud be

```
var ellements = frame.contentWindow.document
   .getElementsByClassName("ms-globalbreadcrumb");
for(i in ellements) {
  ellements[i].style.display = "none";
}
```